# Prevent Rails from escaping saved html to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sanitization, aloha-editor

I'm trying to save the following inside a textarea to one of my models:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar7PxP76o28" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However this is what it actually ends up saving:

```
&lt;iframe width=\"560\" \r\nheight=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar7PxP76o28\" \r\nframeborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

Is there any way I can prevent it from escaping the html? I'm trying to render a youtube embeded video inside of the show view using the following code:

```
= @foo.content.html_safe
```

However the `html_safe` helper doesn't seem to work if the html is escaped like this. I also tried swapping out html_safe with a `raw` wrapper but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Some gem is probably doing that for you - Rails does not do this out of the box AFAIK. Show us your Gemfile.

Comment: Aha! I never even thought to look for that. It actually ended up being some WYSIWYG editor Javascript that was sanitizing the html for me. Thanks for the point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zabba suggested there was actually a third-party involved that was causing this issue and not Rails itself. In my case I was using the Aloha WYSIWYG editor which was sanitizing any custom HTML that I added to my form without my permission.